# Can I hook up to any forms authentication sign out event?

Tags: asp.net, events, forms-authentication

I would like to do som extra processing whenever a user is signed out from forms authentication.

According to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/467h1csc.aspx)
there is a

> FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate

event but I need something like a

> "FormsAuthentication_OnSignOut" (Which doesn't exist)

Any ideas?

/J

Comment: Would `Session_End` provide what you need?  Forms doesn't work the same way, it checks on the next server hit and says "hey your ticket's not valid", so no way for it to fire an event like `Session_End` would (after 20 min of idle, or whatever)

Comment: I was looking for a way to explicitly hook into whenever an explicit FormsAuthentication.SignOut() was called. We are hosting a few apps sharing forms authentication across servers and it would be nice to do some extra tidying up when we know the user chose to sign out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have been able to find out there are no way to make this hook.

You have to add any extra code to the place where you do the FormsAuthentication.Signout().

(Of course you could apply some AOP techniques but this was not relevant in my case)

Answer (score 1):

Keep the user signed in until they explicitly sign out - and when they click the logout link use something like the following:

private void OnLogOut (Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      FormsAuthentication.SignOut ();
      //extra processing here
  }